# How do I fade in/fade out the contents as the jQuery slide activates and deactivates?

Tags: jquery

Right now, I have my slide set up and it works fine but I'd like the contents of the slide (#contact-slide) to fade in as the slide activates (slides down) and fade out as the slide deactivates (slides up).

Here is my html:

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="slide-container">
        <section id="contact-slide">
            <section id="contact-form">
                <a href="#" id="slide-up"></a>
                <section id="contact-about">
                    <h2>Who is <span class="green">Company</span>?</h2>
                    <p>We are blah blah blah...</p>
                </section>
                <section id="contact-data">
                    <h2>Get in <span class="green">touch</span>!</h2>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>​
```

Below is the js. You can see I tried to insert `$('#contact-slide').fadeOut();` on line 4 but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
  $('a#slide-up').click(function () {
    $('.slide-container').slideUp(400,'easeOutExpo',function(){
      $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $('#contact-slide').fadeOut();
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('a#slide-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var slideToggle = this;
    if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
      $('.slide-container').slideUp(400,'easeOutExpo',function() {
        $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
      });
    }
    else {
      $('.slide-container').slideDown(300,'easeInExpo');
      $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
    }
  });
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `animate` method to animate the opacity from 0 to 1 and vice versa because `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` will not fit perfectly here. Try this.

```
$('a#slide-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var slideToggle = this;
    if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
      $('.slide-container').slideUp(400,'easeOutExpo',function() {
        $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
      }).animate({
         opacity: 0
      }, 400);
    }
    else {
      $('.slide-container').slideDown(300,'easeInExpo')
      .animate({
         opacity: 1
      }, 300);

      $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but nothing changed. The content does not fade in/out.